# tf view_frames syntax error

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have Indigo ROS and Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS. Few month ago when I run `rosrun tf view_frames`, it worked, but now it gives me a SyntaxError (as seen in the picture). I can't fix the syntax, because I don't have a permission to change files inside ros folder.

Is there any solution to this problem?

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-MS-7817:~$ rosrun tf view_frames 
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/tf/view_frames", line 57
    print "Listening to /tf for %f seconds"%duration
                                          ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(int "Listening to /tf for %f seconds"%duration)?
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/283947/tf-view_frames-syntax-error/) by [Kri](https://answers.ros.org/users/33914/kri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2018-02-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-28**:
I just let your post out of the moderation queue, but if I would apply the [support guidelines](http://wiki.ros.org/Support) strictly, I should immediately close it. Was:

```
Please DO NOT post a screenshot of the terminal or source file.
```

Not clear enough?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-28**:
As to your issue: have you installed Anaconda or Python 3 between now and "few months ago"? If so, it could be that python3 is now the default interpreter, and `view_frames` has not been made Python 3 compatible yet, leading to the syntax error.

**Comment by [Kri](https://answers.ros.org/users/33914/kri/) on 2018-03-01**:
@gvdhoorn I'm sorry, I didn't see the guidelines before. Luckily my issue isn't of that sort that would require copying the error to find out what is wrong.

**Comment by [Kri](https://answers.ros.org/users/33914/kri/) on 2018-03-01**:
@gvdhoorn I don't remember doing anything with python ever on this computer, but my roommates might. I wouldn't know. Is there a way how to change the default python interpreter version?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-01**:\

> I didn't see the guidelines before

they were shown to you almost fullscreen when you created your post.

> my issue isn't of that sort that would require copying the error to find out what is wrong

I'd still like you to replace the image with the copy-pasted text of the error.

**Comment by [Kri](https://answers.ros.org/users/33914/kri/) on 2018-03-01**:
@gvdhoorn I have edited the question. Is this done right?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-01**:
That's great. Thanks.

As to your problem: what is the output of `python --version`?

**Comment by [simff](https://answers.ros.org/users/31951/simff/) on 2018-03-01**:
An alternative way to view tf frames is: rosrun rqt_tf_tree rqt_tf_tree. This requires to have [this](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_tf_tree) into your workspace :)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-01**:
That would be a possible work-around yes, but it might be better to get to the bottom of this so we can make sure it's not an issue with the packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@gvdhoorn it used to output 'python3' I have changed it into 'python2,' but the error remained. I used a command `which python` to see the path and discovered it leads to python2 inside miniconda3 folder. I have deleted the miniconda3 folder and now it works. Thank you for your patience and help.

---

Originally posted by [Kri](https://answers.ros.org/users/33914/kri/) with karma: 41 on 2018-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-01**:
Let's make this the answer. I would still it if you could check whether you are up-to-date, as the exact problem you are reporting should have been fixed (on 2017-07-24 already).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-01**:
@Kri: afaict, [ros/geometry#151](https://github.com/ros/geometry/pull/151) should have resolved some lingering python2/3 issues with `tf`, even on Indigo. Can you make sure you're up-to-date?

**Comment by [Kri](https://answers.ros.org/users/33914/kri/) on 2018-03-01**:
@gvdhoorn I don't know how to do that. I don't even understand what that means, which makes it hard to search for.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-01**:
When was the last time you did an `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`, or used the Ubuntu Software Centre to update your ROS packages (assuming you use Ubuntu)?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-01**:
Note that I'm not saying you should upgrade *now*. I just want to figure out why you're running into this issue which should have already been fixed quite some time ago.

**Comment by [Kri](https://answers.ros.org/users/33914/kri/) on 2018-03-01**:
That might me problematic. I did that few days ago, but since then the updated ubuntu doesn't get pass login screen (update broke something). Therefor I have to chose older version of ubuntu from GRUB. I don't know what else is not up to date when I run on the older version.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-01**:
Ok. Let's just chalk this up to using an unsupported Python version for now, and assume it has been fixed in recent versions of `tf`.